# Impor atributo !important de CSS inline

Tags: html, css, atributos

Tenho um problemão pra resolver aqui e mesmo achando que não tem solução quero uma ajuda, vai que eu não esteja vendo o problema como um todo...

Tenho o seguinte código em uma página:

```css
.elemento {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento">
  <p>Tudo aqui dentro de .elemento, incluindo este parágrafo é importante ser exibido, exceto o link abaixo:</p>
  <a href="#" target="_blank" style="animation: none!important;background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);url('...')no-repeat 8px center !important;border: none!important;border-radius: 6px!important;bottom: auto!important;box-sizing: border-box!important;color: rgba(0,0,0,.5)!important;display: inline-block!important;float: none!important;font-family: Roboto,Arial,Sans-serif!important;font-size: 12px!important;font-weight: 700!important;height: 28px!important;left: 50%!important;line-height: 16px!important;margin: 8px auto!important;opacity: 1!important;padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px!important;position: relative!important;right: auto!important;text-align: left!important;text-decoration: none!important;text-indent: 0!important;top: auto!important;transform: translateX(-50%)!important;visibility: visible!important;max-width: 240px!important;z-index: 99999!important;zoom: 1!important;background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.9)!important;">Problema</a>
</div>
```

Eu preciso ocultar a tag `<a></a>` usando somente CSS, o problema é que o CSS inline inteiro desse link está com `!important` e eu não posso ocultar/remover seu elemento pai, pois os irmãos precisam ser exibidos. Os pseudo-elementos `::before` e `::after` não estão definidos.

Há alguma maneira de ocultar sem usar JS?

Comment: Cara não entendo direito, vc quer dar um display:none no <a> dentro da div.elemento? Não ficou claro o que vc quer

Comment: Com JS é só apagar o style e colocar o que você quer. Exemplo: `document.querySelector('.elemento > a').style = "display: none !important;"`

Comment: Sem JS você vai ver que o `style` com `!important` tem precedência ao CSS... Então a resposta é que não tem como fazer isso sem gambiarra. Sem contar que pelo `style` do elemento, é nítido que quem criou o elemento não queria que fosse apagado.

Comment: @hugocsl é isso mesmo, quero deixar o elemento a invisível.

Comment: @fernandosavio então. Realmente essa é a intenção de quem criou o elemento... Queria encontrar um meio/gambiarra para conseguir ocultar. Pode até ser com gambiarra, não tem problema. O problema está em usar JS.

Comment: Então o segredo é listar todas as propriedades CSS que o elemento usa e descobrir uma maneira de esconder o elemento usando qualquer propriedade que não conste no `style`.

Comment: @fernandosavio eu dei uma olhada e parece q, infelizmente, foi usado todas as propriedades possíveis

Comment: É, são más notícias... Agora você só pode torcer que alguém ache uma brecha nisso.

Comment: Realmente está difícil, só vejo uma maneira de resolver isso.... para resolver uma gambiarra normalmente vc precisa de outra gambiarra :/

Comment: @fernandosavio Duas soluções =) o cara que fez esqueceu do `filter: opacity()` haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talves isso te ajude, eu removi todos os eventos de mouse do elemento com os CSS descritos abaixo, e encobri o `<a>` com um *pseudo-elemento* `::after` por cima dele e com a mesma cor do fundo.

A dica, e vc colocar no HTML `tabindex="-1"`, para o `<a>` ficar inacessível mesmo via teclado.

```css
.elemento {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px
}

.elemento > a {
    /* remove os eventos de mouse */
    user-select: none;
    cursor: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.elemento > a::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento">
    <p>Tudo aqui dentro de .elemento, incluindo este parágrafo é importante ser exibido, exceto o link abaixo:</p>
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" target="_blank" style="animation: none!important;background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);url('...')no-repeat 8px center !important;border: none!important;border-radius: 6px!important;bottom: auto!important;box-sizing: border-box!important;color: rgba(0,0,0,.5)!important;display: inline-block!important;float: none!important;font-family: Roboto,Arial,Sans-serif!important;font-size: 12px!important;font-weight: 700!important;height: 28px!important;left: 50%!important;line-height: 16px!important;margin: 8px auto!important;opacity: 1!important;padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px!important;position: relative!important;right: auto!important;text-align: left!important;text-decoration: none!important;text-indent: 0!important;top: auto!important;transform: translateX(-50%)!important;visibility: visible!important;max-width: 240px!important;z-index: 99999!important;zoom: 1!important;background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.9)!important;">Problema</a>
</div>
```

---

***EDIT:*** **Opção número 2** (essa é até melhor que a primeira rss)

Como o elemento não tem filter, vc pode usar o `filter: opacity(0);` e depois usar as classes para retirar os eventos de mouse e o `tabindex` no html. Assim não precisa de *pseudo-elemento*

```css
.elemento {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px
}

.elemento > a {
    filter: opacity(0);

    /* remove os eventos de mouse */
    user-select: none;
    cursor: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="elemento">
    <p>Tudo aqui dentro de .elemento, incluindo este parágrafo é importante ser exibido, exceto o link abaixo:</p>
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#" target="_blank" style="animation: none!important;background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);url('...')no-repeat 8px center !important;border: none!important;border-radius: 6px!important;bottom: auto!important;box-sizing: border-box!important;color: rgba(0,0,0,.5)!important;display: inline-block!important;float: none!important;font-family: Roboto,Arial,Sans-serif!important;font-size: 12px!important;font-weight: 700!important;height: 28px!important;left: 50%!important;line-height: 16px!important;margin: 8px auto!important;opacity: 1!important;padding: 6px 6px 6px 32px!important;position: relative!important;right: auto!important;text-align: left!important;text-decoration: none!important;text-indent: 0!important;top: auto!important;transform: translateX(-50%)!important;visibility: visible!important;max-width: 240px!important;z-index: 99999!important;zoom: 1!important;background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.9)!important;">Problema</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nossa, boa!! Não estava lembrando do `opacity` em `filter`. Eu tinha testado usando *pseudo-elemento*, mas não tinha ficado tão bom. Com o `filter` ficou do jeito que eu precisava hehe. Brigadão Hugo! ;)

Comment: Merece palmas... É uma gambiarra digna! hahahaha Ganhou meu +1

Comment: @fernandosavio a vantagem do CSS é que sempre tem um jeitinho de fazer alguma gambiarra... A desvantagem é que tem gente que acha que a gambiarra é o jeito certo :/, tmj

Comment: @LeonardoDias legal que resolveu ai, não esqueça o tab index e aproveite e coloque tb o atributo `hidden` para tb não aparecer para os leitores de tela!

Comment: Infelizmente nesse caso só tem como resolver com gambiarra msm, como vc disse, com CSS tem sempre um jeitinho né! Sobre o tab index eu não consigo colocar, já q eu não tenho acesso direto à estrutura da tag, senão eu poderia só remover os `!important` do `style`. O mesmo vale pro `hidden` :/